# R Plotly : Horizontal Bar chart with Y axis on right

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to plot bar chart with Y axis on right.

Expectation :

[image]

However I am unable to shift the y axis to right. I have tried with side = 'right' but it seems to not work.

```
bar_plot_vertical_left <- function( plot_data , var_y, x_name = '', y_name = 'Y axis',  ... ){

  df = data.frame( plot_data ) ; df = na.omit( df )

  var = quos(...) ; names_vars = names( var ) ; x_vars = names_vars[ startsWith( names_vars, 'var_x' ) ]

  x_var_names = sapply( 1:length( x_vars ), function( j ){ quo_name( var[[ x_vars[j] ]] ) } )

  row_sum = df %>% select( x_var_names ) %>% rowSums()

  yenc = enquo( var_y ) ; cols = colorRampPalette(c("white", "#4C68A2"))( length( x_vars ) )

  #... Plot parameters .....

  font_size = list( size = 12, family = 'Lato' ) ; gray_axis = '#dadada'

  p = plot_ly( data = df, x = var[[ x_vars[1] ]], y = yenc, name = quo_name( var[[ x_vars[1] ]] ), 

               type = 'bar', marker = list( color = cols[1], line = list( color = '#E1E1E1', width = 0.8 ) ), 

               textposition = 'auto', text = var[[ x_vars[1] ]], hoverlabel = list( font = font_size ),

               orientation = 'h'  ) %>%

    layout( title = list( text = 'Vertical left', x = 0, font = list( family = 'Lato black' ) ), barmode = 'stack',

            xaxis = list( title = x_name, showgrid = F, showticklabels = F,  zerolinecolor = gray_axis,

                          tickfont = font_size, titlefont = font_size ),

            yaxis = list( title = paste0( c( rep ("&nbsp;", 20 ), y_name, rep( "&nbsp;", 20 ),

                                             rep( "\n&nbsp;", 3 ) ), collapse = '' ),

                          linecolor = gray_axis, zerolinecolor = gray_axis, side = 'right',

                          tickfont = font_size, titlefont = font_size ),

            legend = list( font = font_size, orientation= 'h', font = font_size,

                           x = 1 , y = 1.2, xanchor = "left", yanchor = 'top' ),

            margin = list( l = 20, r = 100, b = 10, t = 10 )

    )

  if( length( x_vars ) >= 2 ){

    for( i in 2:length( x_vars ) ){

      p = p %>% add_trace( x = var[[ x_vars[i] ]], name = quo_name( var[[ x_vars[i] ]] ),

                           marker = list( color = cols[i], line = list( color = '#E1E1E1', width = 0.8 ) ),

                           textposition = 'auto', text = var[[ x_vars[i] ]],

                           hoverlabel = list( font = font_size ) )

    }

  }

  p =  p %>% add_annotations( xref = 'x', yref = 'y', x = ( row_sum ) + 5, y = yenc,

                              text = paste( row_sum ), font = font_size, showarrow = F )

  p

}

bar_plot_vertical_left( df, var_y = Labels, var_x1 = Aria, var_x2 = Acqua, var_x3 = Fuoco, var_x4 = Terra,

                       var_x5 = Cielo )
```

Getting output as below. Here the y axis shifts to right but the starting of the bars are still from left side. Those need to be start from right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll have to set `autorange="reversed"` on the x axis to get it to behave the way you like.